# Iphone custom slider moves both way

Tags: ios

*[image: In Ios custom slider?]
How can i make this type of custom  slider in iphone, which can be extend from both left and right side?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please check my updated ans

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this example project..It may fullFill your requirement..

[CheckThis](https://github.com/avrahamshuk/ASRangeSlider)

Just import ASRangeSlider class 
And use this Code..

```
ASRangeSlider *slider1 = [[ASRangeSlider alloc] initWithSpectrum:FloatRangeMake(0.0,f)];
[slider1 setThumbBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenImage.png.png"]];
frame.size = self.BlackBackGround.frame.size;
slider1.frame = frame;
[BlackBackGround addSubview:self.slider1];
[slider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(slider1ValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
slider1.value=FloatRangeMake(0.0,f);
```

And

```
-(Void) slider1ValueChanged : (id) sender
{
    CGRect changedFrame = slider1.activeAreaView.frame; // this is your changed frame
    // change the frames of your green image using this frame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many other libraries for this. For instance:
https://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider or
https://github.com/buildmobile/iosrangeslider or
https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider or
https://github.com/evadne/RARangedSlider